# Android spinner layout as matrix

Tags: android, xml, spinner, android-spinner

i am using spinner in my project so that the user can select number from drop down list. I want to use spinner dialog and customize it as a matrix for example 1,2,3 are in one row 4,5,6 are in another row but the user should be able to select 1 or 2. Is this possible and how can i achieve this using one text box in layout.

Answer (score 0):

**I think you can use three button in row per layout and setOnClicklistener in per button.**

You have customView in your adapter like this :

```
private View getCustomView(int position, ViewGroup viewGroup, int type) {

        View view = null;


        if (type == OPEN) {

            view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.spinnerlistcurrencyopen_common, viewGroup, false);


        } else if (type == CLOSE) {

            view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.spinnerlistcurrencyclose_common, viewGroup, false);
        }

       //find view by id your buttons here

        return view;
```

}

And you have layout in open mode like this (R.layout.spinnerlistcurrencyopen_common) :

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="3"
>

    <Button android:id="@+id/button1"
            ...
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/button2"
            ...
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        ...
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I thought same think before but there should be another way to order spinner items in layout.